# Angular Nested Controllers Access ng-repeat data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two controllers, one nested inside the other, both using ng-repeat to essentially list arrays of related data. I'd like to access one of the properties in the ng-repeat of the parent controller in the child controller. I'm pretty new to Angular and not sure how to get this working or if I'm approaching it the wrong way. Any guidance would be helpful.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="task" ng-controller="TaskController as taskCtl" ng-repeat="task in tasks">
         {{task.name}}
         <ul>
             <li ng-controller="AttachmentController as attachmentCtl" ng-repeat="attachment in attachments">{{attachment.name}}</li>
         </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('TaskController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.tasks = [{name:'thing1', id: '123456'}, ... ];
}]);

app.controller('AttachmentController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
   $scope.attachments = [];

   $scope.init = function init() {
      $http.get('/api/attachments&task_id=' + **HOW_DO_I_GET_TASK_ID_HERE** )
         .then(function(response) {
              $scope.attachments = response.data;
      });
   };

  $scope.init();
}]);
```

I'd like to load the attachments as they relate to the tasks based on the task id for a given iteration through ng-repeat. Not sure if I'm going about this the wrong way.

Thanks

Comment: Since you're using `$scope` this kind of thing: `ng-controller="TaskController as taskCtl"` is unnecessary, it should be only `ng-controller="TaskController"`.

Comment: @developer033 Thanks ... not sure I understand why/how using $scope makes that unnecessary. Can you elaborate on that or what the 2 ways are?

Comment: Take a look: http://codetunnel.io/angularjs-controller-as-or-scope/

Comment: @developer033 thanks, that makes the whole issue much more clear. I had combined the two having seen it done both ways but not understanding the differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it would be better to use a ng-repeat with a filter on all the attachments with the given id. Since now you are calling the `/api/attachments&task_id` for each task iteration.

Or to send the list of attachments directly on the `/api/tasks` call. Therefor you could loop them instantly when looping the tasks, without the need of fetching them on each iteration.

A possible solution according to your code provided:

```
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="task" ng-controller="TaskController as taskCtl" ng-repeat="task in tasks">
         {{task.name}}
         <ul>
             <li ng-controller="AttachmentController as attachmentCtl" ng-repeat="attachment in getAttachments(task.id)">{{attachment.name}}</li>
         </ul>
    </div>
</div>


app.controller('AttachmentController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
       $scope.getAttachments = function(id) {
          $http.get('/api/attachments&task_id=' + id)
             .then(function(response) {
                  return response.data;
          });
       };
    }]);
```

Comment: Thanks. I like your idea for the /api/tasks call. The API doesn't work this way currently, but I could make one that does fairly trivially.

Comment: If you can combine 1 API call to also include this data, you'll save on speed (since you load all data at once, on not having 1 rest call to get the tasks , and for each task another api call to get the attachements). Let me know if you need any extra help! :)

Comment: yep, that makes tons of sense and probably the next thing i'll do.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this from the child controller should work:
HTML:

```
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="task" ng-controller="TaskController" ng-repeat="task in tasks">
         {{task.name}}
         <ul>
             <li ng-controller="AttachmentController" ng-repeat="attachment in fetchAttachments(task)">{{attachment.name}}</li>
         </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS
Child Controller:
This fetchAttachments will be called for every iteration of the parent ngRepeat. You will have to "return" the result of the Ajax call to this function for it to work.

```
$scope.fetchAttachments = function (task) {
    // call ajax 
    // return the result of ajax
}
```